# Dataflow Python SDK raising ImportError is pipeline is created in a view

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, google-app-engine-python, apache-beam

i am running the Python Dataflow wordcount_minimal.py example, and is working fine.

Anyway i am now trying to create a pipeline from inside a Flask view, and all keeps on failing because a weird:

`ImportError: Cannot re-init internal module __main__`

This is raised by the `dill` package, more specifically here:

https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/dill.py#L67

I have made some tests, like creating brand new virtualenv, and creating a simple Flask app with no other dependency; all the needed packages are:

```
Flask==0.11.1
google-cloud-dataflow
```

and the issue persists. And nothing found in the issues list on github, both in Dataflow Python SDK and dill package repository.

Comment: Have you removed the __main__ elements from the example, so that you are strictly calling it as a module?

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure i understood what you mean. Here's the view definition: http://pastebin.com/n023zL6S

Whatever url i try to load, it does not work, raising the same exception:

http://pastebin.com/Lgvx7raS

Inspite of the fact that the code can be wrong (i had no chance to run this yet), if i put dataflow code in the source, it raises exception, whatever i do.

Comment: For completeness, i have added a github repository that replicates the issue. Here: https://github.com/brunoripa/dataflowissue

Comment: I just came across this old question. Did you get past that issue? If so, it would be useful for others if you could share your findings. If not, I can try to  reproduce your env and see if I can help.

Comment: No sorry, i had no chance to make it work, and after that my project changed, so can't be any helpful. Would be great if you'd have some time to contribute, but there's some chances also that this has been fixed (some months passed).

Comment: Seems like it could be a problem with  ```save_main_session``` pipeline parameter? Did you use it?

Comment: Hi Marcin, sorry but i am no more on the project. I will update the post with comments, if i'd ever successfully have the chance to test this.